# Spin buttons to up quantity in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have made a spin control that only increments & decrements as an onclick event 
My problem is that i want to restrict it to never be allowed to display below the value of 1. Currently when it shows 1 and i hit the decrement arrow it goes down to zero and from there will continue with -1, -2, -3 etc etc

Is ther a way i can add to this script/function to make the minimum quantity displayed as 1

My Function in the head tag is:

```
  <!---sPIN BUTTONS TO UP QUANTITY---> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function changeVal(n) { 
           document.forms[0].quantity.value = 

 parseInt(document.forms[0].quantity.value) + n; 
      } 
 </script>
```

and my field in the form is:

```
 <td ><input name="quantity" type="text" class="quantity" onfocus="this.blur();" value="1" /></td> 
                    <td style="width:14px;"> 
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
                      <td width="28"><img src="siteImages/btn_up.gif" width="14" height="9" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" onClick="changeVal(1);"></td> 
                   </tr> 
                   <tr> 
                   <td><img src="siteImages/btn_down.gif" width="14" height="9" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" onClick="changeVal(-1);"></td> 
                    </tr>
```

Comment: you can use

 
`if(parseInt(document.forms[0].quantity.value) + n > 1)
{
document.forms[0].quantity.value = 

 parseInt(document.forms[0].quantity.value) + n; 
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use an if condition to check whether the new value would be non zero, and only change the form element's value if this is the case.

```
function changeVal(n) { 
    var el = document.forms[0].quantity;
    var newval = parseInt(el.value) + n;
    if (newval > 0) {
        el.value = newval;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record:

```
function changeVal(n) {
  var el = document.forms[0].quantity;
  el.value = Math.max(parseInt(el.value) + n, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
function changeVal(n) { 
var newVal=parseInt(document.forms[0].quantity.value) + n 
if (newVal<1){ 
 document.forms[0].quantity.value=1; 
} 
else { 
document.forms[0].quantity.value=newVal; 
} 
} 
</script>
```